# UISearchBar doesn't attached with navigation bar when device in landscape

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, screen-orientation

UISearch bar added under the navigation bar.
I use

```
 [videoSearchBar  setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 44)];
```

for ios 7.

When in the landscape mode there is a gap between navigation bar and the search bar.
In earlier versions it shows properly without setFrame.

Below the searchbar there is a tableview.

Comment: The navigation bar height changes between portrait and landscape orientations. Use the `topLayoutGuide` to position your search bar.

Comment: Thanks @albertamg. Could you explain how to do that. Are you referring UI builder or done in programatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The navigation bar height changes between portrait and landscape orientations. Use the `topLayoutGuide` to position your search bar. You can do this in the Interface Builder or programatically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];

    searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSDictionary *views = @{@"v":searchBar,
                            @"topLayoutGuide":self.topLayoutGuide};

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topLayoutGuide][v]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[v]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate

- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```